# I am trying to zip files individually, but the file type is unknown

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file, compression

I am trying to zip some files with an unknown file type individually. I am using the following code in a batch script to do that:

```
@ECHO OFF 
FOR %%A IN (bestbuy*nat*component.cpi*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma2:d256m "%%~nA.7z" "%%A"
```

The code will compress files individually ONLY if the file has an extension. Unfortunately the files that I have don't have any extension. In the code I am trying to zip files by doing a pattern match, the files are getting compressed into ONE file (which I do not want, I want each file compressed individually).

Why does this code create separate zip files when the files have an extension (for example if I add .txt to the end of the files) and when there is no extension the code creates one zipped file.

Can anyone please help me with the code to compress files with unknown file type so that each file gets compressed individually

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is you output if you just run: `FOR %%A IN (bestbuy*nat*component.cpi*) DO echo."%%~nA.7z"`  Just want to make sure that the `~n` file name parser is correctly parsing the file names as unique.

Comment: What could help is to ommit the `@ECHO OFF` from the bat file and see what the output is. What version of Windows are your running?

Answer (score 1):

You might have been misled by the [7z help file](http://sevenzip.sourceforge.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm) ([alternative URL)](http://en.helpdoc-online.com/7-zip_9.20/source/cmdline/commands/add.htm) where he writes

> 7-Zip doesn't uses the system wildcard parser. 7-Zip doesn't follow the archaic rule by which *.* means any file. 7-Zip treats *.* as matching the name of any file that has an extension. To process all files, you must use a * wildcard.

At this point in your batch file where you are providing the wildcard parameters 7z.exe is not involved. On a Windows system the command line should read:

```
FOR %%A IN (bestbuy*nat*component*)  DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a –mx9   –m0=lzma:d=256m "%%~nA.7z" "%%A"
```

I have changed the `–m0` parameter as it does not match my specifications in the version I am running. After these slight modifications it works fine for me.

**Update:**

Here is the output from my test environment:

```
C:\Temp> 7zip.bat
C:\Temp> FOR %A IN (7*test*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma:d=256m %~nA.7z %A
C:\Temp> "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma:d=256m 7ziptest_1.7z 7ziptest_1.txt
7-Zip [64] 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-02-03
Scanning
Creating archive 7ziptest_1.7z
Compressing  7ziptest_1.txt
Everything is Ok
C:\Temp> "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma:d=256m 7ziptest_2.7z 7ziptest_2.txt
7-Zip [64] 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-02-03
Scanning
Creating archive 7ziptest_2.7z
Compressing  7ziptest_2.txt
Everything is Ok
C:\Temp> "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma:d=256m 7ziptest_3.7z 7ziptest_3
7-Zip [64] 4.65  Copyright (c) 1999-2009 Igor Pavlov  2009-02-03
Scanning
Creating archive 7ziptest_3.7z
Compressing  7ziptest_3
Everything is Ok
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i still have the same issue even with your code. I changed the code as you suggested but it still zips those files into one file instead of creating a separate zip file for each file.
FOR %%A IN (bestbuy*nat*component*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 -m0=lzma:d=256m %%~nA.7z %%A                                                                   Kind Help

Comment: Doesn’t he need to keep the `%%A` in quotes in case he has a file with space(s) in its name?

Comment: Ok. That's true with the quotes for files with spaces. Point taken. I think a list of files from @JasonMander's directory would help solve the problem. As I stated: The code works for me with my test files.

Comment: File name: bestbuy_abocom_20121002071039_nat_component.cpi-121002124501_653343675_ff  File Extension: cpi-121002124501_653343675_ff  File name: bestbuy_casemate_metrics_request_523_20121219_16-52.txt-20121219165227 File Extension: txt-20121219165227 File Name: bestbuy_huntkey_20121002071039_nat_component File Extension: File. Above are the three types of files that i want to compress individually using a batch script. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the file list. Looking at this list and comparing it to the search string, this would mean that only the first file would be zipped. The second file doesn't match `nat*component` and the third file doesn't match `component.cpi` in the search string.

Comment: After running a test with your list I came to the conclusion that `FOR %%A IN (bestbuy*nat*component*) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a –mx9 –m0=lzma:d=256m "%%~fA.7z" "%%A"` might be the better solution, because it accounts for the file extension. I changed `%%~nA.7z` to `%%~fA.7z` ( %%~fA.7z = fully qualified name instead of only the filename w/o extension as in your initial try). As pointed out by @Scott the command should also contain the double quotes in case of spaces in the file name.